# How to Merge Date and Time?

Tags: date-and-time, time-series

Given the following time series data where row is date and column is time intervals.

```
   rawdata = {{"Date", "08:00", "08:30", "09:00", "09:30", "10:00", "10:30", 
      "11:00", "11:30", "12:00", "12:30", 
      "13:00"}, {{2011, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0.}, 47., 59., 71., 77., 115., 111., 
      103., 75., 101., 121., 135.}, {{2011, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0.}, 20., 51., 
      33., 68., 97., 82., 101., 78., 104., 119., 
      137.}, {{2011, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0.}, 3., 39., 61., 59., 63., 108., 66., 
      85., 108., 119., 114.}, {{2011, 1, 7, 0, 0, 0.}, 13., 55., 74., 70.,
       105., 95., 71., 82., 86., 113., 124.}}
```

I can't figure out how to merge date and time together so that my desired output will be

```
output = {{Date}, {{2011, 1, 4, 8, 0, 0.}, 47.}, {{2011, 1, 4, 8, 30, 0.}, 
  59.}, {{2011, 1, 4, 9, 0, 0.}, 71.}, ..., {{2011, 1, 6, 13, 0, 0.}, 
  124}}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

```
With[{data = #}, 
   MapThread[{#1, #2} &, {(#1 + DateList[#2]*{0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}) & @@@
       Tuples[{data[[2 ;;, 1]], Rest[data[[1]]]}], 
     Flatten[data[[2 ;;, 2 ;;]]]}]] &[rawdata]
```

All those excess characters... Here's the Twitterized version:

```
Transpose@{(#1 + DateList[#2]*{0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}) & @@@\
   Tuples@{#[[2 ;;, 1]], #[[1, 2 ;;]]}, Flatten@#[[2 ;;, 2 ;;]]} &[rawdata]
```

Comment: Good idea with this `-DateList["00:00"]`, isn't it? :) +1 for handling the `Tuples` and `MapThread` usage.

Comment: @Kuba: yes, I *hated* the ugliness of my original...+1 back for inspiration!

Comment: @rasher nice and compact +1

Answer (score 4):

Here is an approach using `rawdata` in the question:

```
ans = Module[{time, dates, dt, values},
   time = 
    ToExpression /@ (StringSplit[#, ":"] & /@ Rest@First@rawdata);
   dates = rawdata[[2 ;;, 1]];
   values = rawdata[[2 ;;, 2 ;;]];
   dt = Map[Function[x, Join[x[[1 ;; 3]], #, {0}] & /@ time], dates];
   Flatten[MapThread[{#1, #2} &, {dt, values}, 2], 1]];
```

**Checking**

Displaying as a table:

```
Grid[{DateString[#1], #2} & @@@ ans]
```

[image]

Plotting:

```
DateListPlot[ans]
```

Headings (as in desired answer) can just be prepended to `ans`.

[image]

Or if the desire is plot by value by time of day (as per Chris Degnen):

```
DateListPlot[Transpose[ans], Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Or if each row represents a time series that is desired to be plotted a different color:

```
DateListPlot[Partition[ans, Length@rawdata[[1]] - 1], Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: @rasher thank you for kindness...nice use of `DateList`...always learn something here

Answer (score 3):

```
Flatten[
 Table[
   {rawdata[[ i, 1]] + DateList[rawdata[[ 1, j]]] - DateList["0:00"],
    rawdata[[ i, j]]},
   {i, 2, Length[rawdata] - 1},
   {j, 2, Length[rawdata[[ 1]]] - 1}]
 , 1]
```

> ```
>  {{{2011,1,4,8,0,0.},47.},<<28>>,{{2011,1,6,12,30,0.},119.}}
> ```

Comment: This code does not return the output as I want because it will not consider the time in each column.  Thank you for the good example.

Comment: @newbie sorry for my mistake, fixed now.

Comment: @Kuba use of `DateList` (and removing date offset) by you and rasher...much nicer than my ham fisted manual approach: +1

Comment: @ubpdqn Thanks, but I suspect there is something even more clean. I've failed to find it :/

Answer (score 2):

The following method could be made more compact, but it would be less clear to read :-

```
minutes = Map[Join[{0, 0, 0}, ToExpression@StringSplit[#, ":"], {0}] &,
   Rest@First@rawdata];

records = Rest@rawdata;

merge[rec_] := Module[{date, data, times},
  date = First@rec;
  data = Rest@rec;
  times = ConstantArray[date, Length@data] + minutes;
  Transpose[{times, data}]]

output = Prepend[Flatten[merge /@ records, 1], {rawdata[[1, 1]]}];

DateListPlot[Transpose[Partition[Rest@output, 11]], Joined -> True]
```

[image]